# Bootstrap Card Shrinks after Search Button Clicked

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I am pretty new to Boostrap, I've mainly been doing backend stuff, but am now doing front end work. I have a feature where the user searches a place and a list of nearby venues pops up. I'd like these to pop up in a card. I am using bootstrap cards.

When I execute a search the card snaps down to a tiny scrollable version and all the content divs (map/card) seem to drop down a tad.

[image]

What I'd like to achieve is a standard height for the card after search.

Here is the for the initial card:

```
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Places Nearby</h5>
              <div id="cafes">
                <div id="cafe_list"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the html for the function that generates the list:

```
<div class="cafe-details d-flex">
            <ul>
              {% for cafe in cafes %}
              <li>
                <address>
                  <div>
                    <h6 class="cafe-name" data-id="{{ cafe.id }}">{{ cafe.cafe_name }}</h6>
                    <p>{{ cafe.cafe_address }}</p>
                  </div>
                </address>
                <p>
                  <a href="">Add to List</a> / <a href="">Recommend</a>
                </p>
                </li>
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.card {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100px;
   border: 1px;
   top: 75px;
   bottom: 10px;
   left: 25px;
   z-index: 10040;
   overflow: auto;
   overflow-y: auto;
}

.cafe-details {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Your card collapses to a tiny scrollable version because of the `.cafe-details {position: absolute;}` style. What do you need it for? With regard to the "big clumsy empty card" I can't be of any help since I can't reproduce it. If you insert a working snippet with the faulty behavior maybe I can help.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What would I change the position css to? I removed it and still have the same problem. I want to it to act as a container for a list of cafes nearby the user's search location. 

I have removed the "clumsy" empty card part to make this question a bit tighter, apologies.

Comment: I have added an answer with Snippet to demonstrate. If your problem persists I will need your whole css and html code (returned from server with results). Or even better insert a snippet with the faulty behavior if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.cafe-details {position: absolute;}` style.

```css
.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px;
  top: 75px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 25px;
  z-index: 10040;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>This is my web page</p>
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Places Nearby</h5>
      <div id="cafes">
        <div id="cafe_list">

          <div class="cafe-details d-flex">
            <ul>

              <li>
                <address>
                  <div>
                    <h6 class="cafe-name" data-id="some_cafe_id">some_cafe_name</h6>
                    <p>some_cafe_address</p>
                  </div>
                </address>
                <p>
                  <a href="">Add to List</a> / <a href="">Recommend</a>
                </p>
              </li>

              <li>
                <address>
                  <div>
                    <h6 class="cafe-name" data-id="another_cafe_id">another_cafe_name</h6>
                    <p>another_cafe_address</p>
                  </div>
                </address>
                <p>
                  <a href="">Add to List</a> / <a href="">Recommend</a>
                </p>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```